# How do I use a 4×4 viewfinder grid for composition?

Tags: composition, composition-basics, grid

I decided to use my Nokia N8 for photography with Camera Pro on it because of the tilt, GPS and compass capabilities along with the 5 photo exposure bracketing for postprocessing.

But then this is the only grid I can use.
[image: 4x4 Grid?]

This is the weirdest grid I have ever seen in my life. The rectangles aren't equal and the ones on the sides are smaller?

So:

- What is the name of that grid?
- How am I supposed to use it?
- What is it designed to be used for?

Comment: Do you want to use a grid? What for? To ensure the horizon is level, etc? What's wrong with this grid? What does it not allow you to do?

Comment: @osullic I have never used nor saw that 4x4 grid in my life. I have always used that classic 3x3 grid and I do t know how to use this grid to make photographs look "nice" and I am looking for an tutorial to use that grid "effectively". I don't know how to compose the photos with this grid that's all. (I know how to level the horizon by using the horizontal lines.)

Comment: (the 4x4 grid is not that rare (nikon use it in the dslr viewfinder) ) The grid is good to not force the photographer to a certain rule like the golden ratio. so it is more for a rough approximation and to geht your photo straight